# Trouble loading Stan model output using readRDS

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, rstan

I am running a Bayesian latent variable model in `Stan`. Here is my code for the model:

```
# run the Stan model 
mod.dyn <- stan(file="DynamicLVMmin.stan",
                data=stan.data, seed=570175513, thin = 5,
                iter=10000)
```

The model runs with no issue. I then go to save the `mod.dyn` as follows:

```
# save stan fit 
saveRDS(mod.dyn, "dynamic_fit.rds")
```

Now I am reading `dynamic_fit.rds`. I want to assess model convergence using the Gelman-Rubin R-hat diagnostic. Here is the code:

```
readRDS("dynamic_fit.rds")



params <- c("innov", "c_n_4_v2exdfdshs", "c_n_5_v2exdfvths", "c_n_3_v2exdfpphs", "c_n_5_v2lginvstp", 
            "c_n_3_v2lgoppart", "c_n_2_v2lgfunds", "c_n_4_v2lgcomslo", "c_n_2_v2lgintbup", "c_n_2_v2lgintblo", 
            paste("beta[", 1:9, "]", sep=""))

params.all <- names(mod.dyn)
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Error: object 'mod.dyn' not found
Execution halted
```

What am I missing here? Shouldn't `mod.dyn` have been saved when I used `saveRDS(mod.dyn, "dynamic_fit.rds")`. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readRDS` saves a single object without a name. So you want to use

```
mod.dyn <- readRDS("dynamic_fit.rds")
```

to capture that value after you read it in. This is different than `save()/load()` which store one or more variables with their name+value in a serialized format. If you did

```
save(mod.dyn, file="dynamic_fit.rdata")
```

then

```
load("dynamic_fit.rdata")
```

the object `mod.dyn` would be loaded back into your workspace.

Comment: so this means I should not use `readRDS("dynamic_fit.rds")` by itself but rather mod.dyn <- readRDS("dynamic_fit.rds")'? Or both?

Comment: If you use `readRDS` without saving the result to a variable name, it will just print to the screen then disappear. If you you want to interact with that object, then you'll need to save it to a variable. So most of the time there's no point in calling it without the `<-`